# Issue with external .js file

Tags: javascript

```js
function showPopUp() {
 var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout ?");
 
 if (isConfirmed) {
  window.location = "./logout";
 }
};

function isEmpty(){
 console.log("isEmpty");
};
```

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
form {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px
}
input {
  margin-bottom:3px;
  padding:10px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #CCC
}
button {
  padding:10px
}
label {
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/js/customJavaScript.js"></script>
<link href="/MyProject/css/LoginRegister.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id='login-form' action="./login" method='POST'>
 <label></label>
    <input onkeyup="isEmpty()" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" required>
   <input onkeyup="isEmpty()" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type='submit'>Login</button>
    <label><a href="./register">Register</span></label>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

js file with two functions in.
The File:

```
function showPopUp() {
var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout ?");

    if (isConfirmed) {
       window.location = "./logout";
    }
}

function isEmpty(){
     console.log("isEmpty");
}
```

I am importing the file in the jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/js/customJavaScript.js'/>"></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/"/>css/LoginRegister.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id='login-form' action="./login" method='POST'>
   <label>${errorMsg}</label>
      <input onkeyup=showPopUp() type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input onkeyup=isEmpty() type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type='submit'>Login</button>
    <label><a href="./register">Register</span></label>
</form>
<c:remove var="errorMsg" scope="session"/></body></html>
```

When activate the onkeyup on the input with the shopPupUp function it is working perfectly the confirm is show and it is fine.

But when i activate the onkeyup on the input with the isEmpty function i am getting the following error in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: isEmpty is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: do you have another input somewhere where you have `onkeyup=Empty()` instead of `onkeyup=isEmpty()` ?

Comment: also shouldn't the function be in inverted commas like `onkeyup="isEmpty()"`?

Comment: Please provide a snippet or fiddle that allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: For the first question, no i dont have other input where i have Empty instread of isEmpty.

Comment: For the second question i tried this one too it is still not working. And i am calling showPopUp again without the quotes.

Comment: trincot how should i do this when i am using a jsp ?

Comment: Get the source of the page that is generated by JSP (use `view source` from context menu in browser). The `HTMLInputElement.onkeyup` error is not generated by JSP, but by the browser -- on the HTML that is generated -- so no need to reproduce the JSP code.

Comment: So i've done the snippet but it shown's that it is working there when i it actually not.... :D.

Comment: And still the biggest issue for me is why the showPopUp function is called without probmlen on the onkeyup event and the isEmpty is not is there some kind of dependency or rule how should be the file structured ?

Comment: Obviously that means the snippet is not the same as the page you are having the problem with. As everything works as it should in what you have provided, there is also nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It appears the problem is with Chrome I just tried it in Firefox and it is working. So do u have any idea how should I resolve this for Chrome or atleast point me what to check for ?

Comment: It was a cache issue i guess. When i deleted the browsing data(Ctrl + Shift + Del) check the cached images and file checkbox + delete the problem is solved... And still thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The combination `Ctrl + Shift + Del` in *Chrome*. Check the cached imaged and files checkbox and click on Clear Browsing Data fixed the issue.